# ¿Como reproducir un audio en un activity automaticamente y que no se reproduzca a la siguiente Activity?

Tags: android

Encontre un codigo que reproduce el audio en un activity y a cualquier momento al dar click en el boton para redeireccionar a otro activity se sigue reproduciendo el audio, como puedo hacer para que no se reprodusca el audio cuando pase a otra activity utilice el siguiente codigo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantalla_bienvenida);

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bienvenida);
mediaPlayer.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

agrega this.finish(); al boton para cambiar de activity y agrega este codigo a tu activity donde reproduces el sonido:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
 super.onDestroy();
 if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
  mediaPlayer.stop();
 }
}
```